# BDC Filtering Operator Options - SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint 2007 BDC Instance setup with a method that includes a simple filter on it, but I am coming up just a tad short in the definition to give me the desired Operator option in the filtering options of the Business Data List web part.

Using the web services I was given, my "Finder" web method implements the equivalent of a query that looks like:

```
     SELECT * FROM Customers where City LIKE '%' + @MyParameter '%'
```

With this query, if I create my FilterDescriptor with either of the below:

```
     <FilterDescriptor Type="Comparison" Name=Parameter />
     <FilterDescriptor Type="Wildcard" Name=Parameter />
```

The first gives me an "Is Equal To" operator option, the second gives me four options: "Contains", "Starts With", "Ends With", and "Is Equal To".  Neither of these are correct because both are misleading to the users since the query is always executing using the "Contains" logic.  I don't want to give them any options beyond "Contains".  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Its probably always executing Contains logic because the way you have written your SQL query.  Change your query to this

```
SELECT * FROM Customers where City LIKE @MyParameter
```

and SharePoint will substitute the proper wildcards for you depending on which option Contains, Starts With, Ends With, Is Equal To the user chooses.

I'm not sure how, or if its possible, to remove the Starts With, Ends With and Is Equal To options from the web part

Comment: Unfortunately, the BDC is pointing at a set of web services, not SQL queries in the application definition file.  And as I mentioned in the original post, the web services does indeed implement the query that way (with "contains") logic. Through some logging, I can tell that all SharePoint passes to the web service is the string, nothing about starts with, ends with, etc. so changing the web services isn't really an option as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit about the web services.  Just saw an SQL query and was thinking database.